# What is the significance of orthogonal bases?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

I'm beginning with Fourier series, and I've just been introduced to the idea that we can define an inner product $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$ as a generalization of the dot product. And that we can have sets of functions that are orthognal (which I'm learning is an abstract non-geometric generalization of the idea of right-angle geometric (orthogonal) vectors. e.g. $sin(kx), k: 1,2,3,...$ are orthogonal to eachother.

**Now my question is: what is the significance of all this? Why do we care whether functions are orthogonal to each other in this abstract sense**? In geometry and with bases in e.g. Euclidean vector spaces, we care because orthogonality has a clear geometric meaning with clear implications. But what is the meaning and what are the implications of having a set of orthogonal functions or an orthogonal basis of a non geometric vector space?

Comment: For example in approximation theory, orthogonal bases are very desirable since they minimize for example the condition number of the matrices appearing in least squares approximations. Using for example the 'usual' basis $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$, we find a very ill-conditioned matrix when you use the inner product you defined (it is called a Hilbert matrix for your interest). It also leads to nice characterizations of the solution to this least squares problem.

Comment: Well actually orthogonal is a word that means much more than geometrically at right angles which is specifically perpendicular, technically the word orthogonal is more general.

Comment: Orthogonality has also been used to model fungal growth in biology: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349500764836

Comment: It greatly simplifies both the calculation, just do an inner product, and interpretation, frequency strength here, of the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "non geometric vector space". In the contrary: The intuition you have from the euclidean space ${\mathbb R}^3$ modeling your everyday surroundings should help you in better understanding the things going on in an infinite dimensional euclidean space.

The essential property of an orthonormal basis $(e_\iota)_{\iota\in I}$ is that it is "self dual". This means that the coordinates $\xi_\iota$ of a given vector $x$ with respect to such a basis  are just given by the scalar products $x\cdot e_\iota$: $$\xi_\iota=x\cdot e_\iota\qquad(\iota\in I)\ .\tag{1}$$
If the basis $(e_\iota)_{\iota\in I}$ (finite or infinite) is not orthonormal then you have to determine a "dual basis" $(e_\iota^*)_{\iota\in I}$ beforehand in a complicated computational process (inversion of some matrix), and  instead of $(1)$ you then have
$$\xi_\iota=x\cdot e_\iota^*\qquad(\iota\in I)\ .$$